# Slideshow with blinking effect

Tags: jquery

I have an endless loop slideshow, the result I'm looking for is: blinking image -> few seconds of blank -> next blinking image, ...

@marcus-ekwall solution almost works, but the very first slide is shown for a long interval instead of short, then it loops fine. Any idea? Thank you

```
$(function(){
$('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
    var $current = $('.slideshow :first-child').hide();
    var $next = $current.next('img');
    $current.appendTo('.slideshow');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $next.show();
    }, 1900);
}, 2000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .slideshow { position:relative; }
    .slideshow img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }​
</style>

<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="1.png" />
        <img src="2.png" />
        <img src="3.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/opohip/10/edit)*

```
  var c=0, n=$('.slideshow img').length;


  var visibleTime  = 2000;
  var hiddenTime   = 200;
  function loop(){
      $('.slideshow img').hide().eq(c++%n).stop().delay(hiddenTime).fadeTo(100,1,function(){
           $(this).delay(visibleTime).fadeTo(100,0,loop);
      });
  }loop();
```

Comment: I need to control the blank interval as well, meaning the time between hide() and the next image

Comment: @anoonimo Edited my answer. I added two vars `visibleTime` and `hiddenTime` just to make the code more self-explanatory, but you can put the vars values directly into their correspondent places. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll need a timeout within your interval. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        var $current = $('.slideshow :first-child').hide();
        var $next = $current.next('img');
        $current.appendTo('.slideshow');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $next.show();
        }, 150);
    }, 300);
});
```

I will also urge you to cache the selectors and image positions for performance gains.

Comment: sorry my comment above was a bit confusing, what I meant: it works but the very first image duration is the whole interval (300) rather than the interval minus timeout (150) which is the one I'm looking for.

After the first one the loop works fine, it's clearer using higher interval and timeout times (i.e. 3000 and 2900)